# Calculation of ever rising value

Tags: php, calculation

I will like to be able to make a calculation in php using a number of experience points (XP) as base to return a level value. I want it to be increasingly more difficult for each level to rise. Like this:

```
0-49 XP = Level 1
50-104 XP = Level 2
105-164 XP = Level 3
165-229 XP = Level 4 etc.
```

To reach level 2 50 XP is needed. To reach level 3 a further 55 XP is needed. To reach level 4 a further 60 XP is needed and so forth.

Even more I would like to be able to display the amount of XP needed to reach the next threshold.

I have no idea what to search for to solve my challenge. I hope you can help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A simple `if..elseif..else`, plus some basic math will do the trick… (Of course that could be made more elegant, but just start with *something* that works…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point structure does not match up with your sentence.

So I'll answer:

> To reach level 2 50 XP is needed. To reach level 3 a further 55 XP is
>   needed. To reach level 4 a further 60 XP is needed and so forth.

```
<?php
$get_level = function () {
    foreach (range(0, 300, 50) as $difficulty => $base) {
        yield [$base + ($difficulty * 5) => 'Level '.($base / 50)];
    }
};

foreach ($get_level() as $base => $level) {
    echo print_r($level, true);
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Level 0
)
Array
(
    [55] => Level 1
)
Array
(
    [110] => Level 2
)
Array
(
    [165] => Level 3
)
Array
(
    [220] => Level 4
)
Array
(
    [275] => Level 5
)
Array
(
    [330] => Level 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Math for the XP calculation is pretty simple:

```
XP = ∑50+5*(level-1)
   = 5*∑10+(level-1)
   = 5*∑9+level
   = 5*(∑9 + ∑level)
   = 5*(9*level + ∑level)
```

The sum over the natural numbers can be looked up in every math book or even Wikipedia.

Comment: This doesn't help @McClaud much as it just gives the formula(?) of the sequence

Comment: And with that formula you can calculate the thresholds. If you invert the formula (which is basic algebra) you can even determine the level from the current XP.

Comment: But you don't explain how to invert the formula _or_ determine the level from the current XP. At most, this answer is just an incomplete/partial algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

In Python (as I don't know PHP very well:( ):

```
levelBoundaries = []
for i in range(number_of_levels_you_want): ## Loop through for all levels

    level = len(levelBoundaries) + 1 ## Get the Level Number


    levelArr = [] ## Create the list for the level boundary
    ## The formula for your list is 2.5n^2 + 42.5n - 45
    ## The level boundary for level n is [Term n, (Term (n+1)) - 1]
    ## This is what has been done below
    levelArr.append((2.5 * (level ** 2)) + (42.5 * level) - 45)
    level += 1
    levelArr.append( (2.5 * (level ** 2)) + (42.5 * level) - 45 - 1)
    levelBoundaries.append(levelArr)
```

Comment: Please can downvoters explain why? (I'm adding an explanation of the code)